# Regex matching to exclude beginning word

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I make the following JavaScript

```
'id=d41c14fb-1d42&'.match(/(?![id=])(.*)[^&]/)[0]
```

return "d41c14fb-1d42"? It currently returns "41c14fb-1d42", without the beginning "d".

Comment: Are you using a regex to parse a query string? If you are, that's OK, but you'd still have to decode parameters, and there's no guarantee the ampersand will be at the end.

Comment: Yes, I am parsing a query string. It needs to be able to handle the *possibility of an ampersand*. Also, *"id=" may not necessarily be located at the beginning of the string*.

Comment: Is this `d41c14fb-1d42` going to be hex chars or is the entire thing delimeted by `id=` ... `&` ?

Comment: Or, how come its not this simple `/id=([^&]*)/` ?

Comment: @DonaldTaylor And percent-encoded characters, so you can't use a regex to extract a single value like this. If you don't call ```decodeURIComponent``` on both the name and value, your approach isn't going to work.

Comment: This "id" will only have alpha-numeric characters and dashes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
'id=d41c14fb-1d42&'.match(/^id=(.*)&$/)[1]
// "d41c14fb-1d42"
```

~ edit

When an original question does not give any context it is hard to guess what you need exactly, in which case I just give a solution that yields the requested output. I now understand you want to be able to parse a query string, i.e., `name1=value1&name2=value2...`. The following regular expression yields `nameX` followed by an optional `=valueX`, as I believe it is valid to provide just the parameter in a query string without a value.

```
var parameters = "id=foobar&empty&p1=javascript&p2=so".match(/\w+(=([^&]+))?/g)
// ["id=foobar", "empty", "p1=javascript", "p2=so"]
```

You can split on "=" to obtain parameter and value separately.

```
var param1 = parameters[0].split("=")
// ["id", "foobar"]
```

For a parameter without the value that would just yield an Array with 1 value, of course.

```
"empty".split("=") // ["empty"]
```

Note this assumes a query parameter to match `\w+`, if there are other cases you have to expand the regular expression.

If you only want to match the `id` parameter specifically anywhere in the query string and obtain its value, as I infer from your comment below, you can use:

```
"id=donald".match(/(?:^|&)id=([^&]+)/)[1]
// "donald"
"param1=value1&id=donald&param2=value2".match(/(?:^|&)id=([^&]+)/)[1]
// "donald"
```

Comment: Could you adjust it to allow the possibility of "id=" not being at the beginning and "&" being optional?

Comment: I would extend this simply to: `/id=(.*?)(?=&|$)/`.

Comment: I mean that "id=" will be present, but may not necessarily be at the beginning.

Comment: How does it handle ```%69%64=...```?

Comment: You should explain what was wrong with the original approach (and point out that this is still, by and large, broken).